# Find the product of the digits of a number

Tags: ocaml

I have to write a recursive function the calculates the product of the digits of a number. What I wrote down is:

```
let rec digits_product x = 
  if x = 0 then 0 
  else 
    let n = x mod 10 in 
    n * digits_product (x / 10)
```

The problem is that it always returns me 0. I am sure there is something I miss out but I can not find out. Can you help me solve the problem? The code should calculate the product of the digits of a number, for example if I enter 12345 it should return 1*2*3*4*5 which is equal to 120.

**UPDATE**

I changed the code to this:

```
let rec digits_product x = 
  match x with    
  | 0 -> 0
  | 1 -> 1
  | 2 -> 2
  | 3 -> 3
  | 4 -> 4
  | 5 -> 5
  | 6 -> 6
  | 7 -> 7
  | 8 -> 8
  | 9 -> 9
  | _ -> (x mod 10) * digits_product (x / 10)
```

It works right now, but I have another question: is there a more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code always makes a recursive call unless the parameter `x` is 0. Since it doesn't show signs of infinite recursion, you know that it is returning 0 at least once. This should be enough to show what is wrong.

**Update**

You are checking the input for 0 because the answer is obvious in that case. But there are other inputs where the answer is obvious. I.e., where you don't need to do any multiplications to get the result. Why not check for all of these? You can check for all of these values with just one test.

Comment: I will give hints if you first explain the reasoning of the current code. I.e., explain how it's supposed to work.

Comment: This is not an explanation of how the code is supposed to work, it's a description of the desired result. For example, why does this fragment appear in your code: `if x = 0 then 0 else...`

Comment: Well, cause if I input 0 the product is 0 I guess :D. I need to make the function stop at some point when there are no more digits to add to the product.

Comment: So is 0 the only input where the answer is known with no further computation?

Comment: I do not say that 0 is the only input. But I need to make the function stop doing the product when all the digits were added to the product. If you can find a better solution then it does not have to be 0. I am at the begining of programming and I am not very used to this kind of stuff. I need to find a way to stop the function when all the digits are added to the product. I just can not think of a way to do it.

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't like long discussions down here in the comments. I updated my answer with some more ideas.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the syntax would look cleaner like so:

```
let rec produsul_cifrelor x =
  match x with
  | n when n < 10 -> n
  | _ -> (x mod 10) * produsul_cifrelor (x/10)
```

Then running `produsul_cifrelor 12345` will return `120`.

Comment: And this is better implemented as `if x < 10 then x else (x mod 10) * produsul_cifrelor (x/10)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been identified by the other answers, but this can provide an example of breaking a problem down. *First* let's get the digits of a number.

```
# let rec digits n =
    if n < 10 then [n]
    else (n mod 10) :: digits (n / 10);;
val digits : int -> int list = <fun>
# digits 1234;;
- : int list = [4; 3; 2; 1]
```

We then simply need a `product` function, which is easy to write and then to apply to the result of `digits`.

```
# let rec product =
    function
    | [] -> 1
    | x::xs -> x * product xs;;
val product : int list -> int = <fun>
# product @@ digits 1234;;
- : int = 24
# let product_digits n = product @@ digits n;;
val product_digits : int -> int = <fun>
# product_digits 12345;;
- : int = 120
```

The `product` function can be implemented as a left fold. This shows how we can play with implementations of these two parts of the problem independently as long as their types remain consistent.

```
# let product = List.fold_left ( * ) 1;;
val product : int list -> int = <fun>
# product @@ digits 234;;
- : int = 24
```

Of course, given that there's no need to actually store a full list of digits to accomplish this, we could use [sequences](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Seq.html).

```
# let rec digits_seq n () =
    if n < 10 then 
      Seq.Cons (n, Seq.empty)
    else 
      Seq.Cons (n mod 10, digits_seq @@ n / 10);;
val digits_seq : int -> int Seq.t = <fun>
# 1234
  |> digits_seq
  |> Seq.fold_left ( * ) 1;;
- : int = 24
```